# Java, ArrayList and Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java

Im iterating through an ArrayList. If I use the old fashion way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
{
    list.get(i).update();;
}
```

it runs ok. But with this:

```
for (Baseitem item : list)
{
    item.update();
}
```

it fails at the first line, inside ArrayList class: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException yes, outside I do remove items - but certainly not while iterating. How to solve this? I dont use any threads.

Comment: What does the `update()` method do? Can you provide a minimal example ([SSCCE](http://sscce.org)) that reproduces the error?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should avoid modifying elements in a list while iterating that list.

With the `for (int i...)` loop, you are not iterating the list, so you can modify the elements inside.

In the `for (Baseitem item : list)` loop, you are iterating the list, so the modification of the elements of the list will raise the `ConcurrentModificationException` exception.

You have to use the first form of the loop if you want to modify the elements inside it.

Comment: You can change the state of an instance during a for each loop without an `ConncurrentModificationException`, see [http://ideone.com/KL1756](http://ideone.com/KL1756). It really depends on what OP is doing in `update();`

Comment: OP is not changing the reference either. At least not in the part of code he presented to us ;)

Comment: Yes but if code raises the exception, then you can imagine that OP is doing something that is not allowed here.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me because I was iterating through a list for removing all the items, with a for loop.

Example `clients` : `[1, 2, 3]`

```
for(int i=0 ; i<clients.size() /* 3 */ ; i++)
    clients.remove(clients.get(i));
```

`i` is going to be `0`, `1` and `2`, but at the third iteration *(`i=2`)* there will be no `clients[2]`, thence `ConcurrentModificationException`.

---

How to avoid the problem:

```
while(clients.size() > 0)
    clients.remove(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

An important note about for-each:

> The for-each loop is used with both collections and arrays. It's
>   intended to simplify the  most common form of iteration, where the
>   iterator or index is used solely for iteration, and  not for any other
>   kind of operation, such as removing or editing an item in the
>   collection or  array. When there is a choice, the for-each loop should
>   be preferred over the for loop, since  it increases legibility.

In your case using iterator is preferable.

Can you also post the `update()` method of `Baseitem` ?